# Text wont load but it reads the txt file

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Hey I am trying to get the textfile inside of the jsx(html)render function. I have made the function handleText which reads the text, and just splits the text up. I can see it in the console log but when i for example try to map it or just insert the myTextArr into render it gives me an empty element for instance a paragraph with no content.

I tried using the map function but without luck so now I just inserted the array inside a p tag but it wont even show there it only loads the p tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try with setState to re-render you text array:

```
   handleText =()=>{
        fetch(text)
            .then((r)=>r.text())
            .then(text => {
                this.setState({myTextArr: [...this.state.myTextArr, text.split(",(?=([^\']*\'[^\']*\')*[^\']*$)")]});
            })
    }
```

Comment: should i refer the myTextArr to state it gives me compile error otherwise?

Comment: still not loading anything  :/

Comment: it works just had to remove ...myTextArr from the setState think it made it keep reading and saving it

Comment: I see, you may call so many time handle texts, i think you should have function handle all texts, and just setState when it's done.

Comment: would you recommend compounentDidMount?

Comment: is something like this in the right direction or? https://gyazo.com/25f153d77f29fb7360bb3b4c16afeb2f

Comment: yes, you can try. But i wonder where do you call this function previously?

Comment: which function do you mean handleText? I called it in the jsx and the browser crashed since it kept loading the text file

Comment: Did you try with componentDidmount? only call one time

Comment: ill try componenDidmount now just read about useEffect im a total noob just started a week ago

Comment: componentDidMount did the trick thanks man ill keep trying to improve :D

Comment: useEffect only is used in Functional Component. Let practise to learn more :))))

Answer (score 1):

Put your text inside a `<span>{text}</span>` instead of `<text>{text}</text>`

Comment: If you want to render a multiline text, you could just put into a `<pre>{text></pre>` tag and style it accordingly (or split it the way you had it and put in different spans or divs)

Comment: I will try when the text is loaded in once i figure out what the problem is! Thanks :)